# Alternate for Web Audio API

Tags: javascript, web, web-audio-api

I have a web program which makes use of Web Audio API. The issue here is that i want to make it compatible for IE. Is there any alternate for the Web Audio API, so that i can make the same code run on IE specifically?

Comment: Which versions of IE?

Comment: Try [howler.js](http://goldfirestudios.com/blog/104/howler.js-Modern-Web-Audio-Javascript-Library)

Comment: IE 11 for now. They are saying it "MIGHT" work for the next version of IE

Comment: If you don't mind ignoring mobile, you can try Flash. They have a Sound Object which supports dynamically generated sound.

Comment: I need an oscillator function, which will generate sounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are your needs? If you need to do dynamic synthesis, audio routing, etc, you will only be able to achieve that with the Web Audio API, so your IE users are out of luck.

However, if all you need to do is play audio files, then I would recommend that you use howler.js.  Howler has great compatibility across different browsers and operating systems, including various versions of IE.

Comment: Ya the issue is that I am dynamically generating sounds, that's the issue.

Comment: I've read that the next version of IE will support the Web Audio API, but I don't know when that will be.

Comment: I need an oscillator function, which will generate sounds

Comment: I generated audio clips of various frequencies and called them using howler and some more script. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft have been working on implementing the web audio API, it looks like a preview implementation is available. https://status.modern.ie/webaudioapi If you can wait until the next version of IE which I believe is expected to be released with Windows 10, which should be out this year IIRC, it may not be worth taking the time to implement an alternative.

That said, to answer your question, there's no way that I could find to generate audio with an oscillator in the web without the Web Audio API other than writing flash code, which has its own major disadvantages.

Minor note: you could possibly hack the html5 audio node to play back audio buffers that you generate in javascript code, but keeping everything in sync and preventing jumps in the waveform would be an awful task.

Comment: What I did was that I wrote a python script to generate wav audio clips by entering the various frequencies as I desired, loaded them onto the server, and then called those audio clips via the javascript using howler. Doesn't work like a charm, but somehow solves the purpose.